# Trouble using pyopengl in Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, error-handling, python-2.x, pyopengl

What I'm trying to do is code a basic OpenGL 2.0 window, when I run the code from a file, it works for the first couple of runs, then it dumps errors. If I run the same exact code from the IDLE GUI, I get a window every time.  The following is first a list of added Python 2.6.6 packages, the code and the errors. Am I using any conflicting packages? Am I missing a package? My imports work in the IDLE GUI. Any help would be great!!

```
Date:   Aug 1, 2011             Time:   03:20:00 AM
This is the listing of packages installed for Python 2.6.6.  
This file was created manually and is meant to be used as a 
reference to show what packages were added in which order

python-2.6.6.msi
setuptools-0.6c11-win32-py26.exe
numpy-1.6.0-win32-superpack-python26.exe
PIL-1.1.7-win32-py26.exe
wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.0-py26.exe
wxPython2.8-win32-docs-demos-2.8.12.0.exe
pyglet-1.1.4.msi
pywin32-216-win32.py32.exe
PyOpenGL-3.0.1.win32.exe
PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.0.1-win32-py26.exe
Pygame-1.9.1-win32-py26.msi
py2exe-0.6.9-win32-py2.6.exe
psyco (using c:\python26\scripts\easy_install psyco)
```

```
    #import sys              #redundant(used to  eval errors)
    #import OpenGL           #redundant(used to  eval errors)       
    #import numpy            #redundant(used to  eval errors)

    #From here down is the original code, with gl imports listed as GLUT/GL/GLU
    #Page 26 PyOpenGL.pdf by Stan Blank, Ph.D
    from OpenGL.GL import *     #These 3 imports are called in a layered format
    from OpenGL.GLU import *    #Fron the simplest to the most complex(complete)
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *

    def draw():
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glutWireTeapot(0.5)
        glFlush()

    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
    glutInitWindowSize(250, 250)
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100)
    glutCreateWindow("Python OGL Program")
    glutDisplayFunc(draw)
    glutMainLoop()
```

```
IDLE error listings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\Python\PyOpenGL\ogl_01.py", line 7, in 
    from OpenGL.GL import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\GL\__init__.py", line 2, in 
    from OpenGL.raw.GL import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\raw\GL\__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.constants import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\raw\GL\constants.py", line 7, in 
    from OpenGL import platform, arrays
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\arrays\__init__.py", line 22, in 
    formathandler.FormatHandler.loadAll()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\arrays\formathandler.py", line 37, in loadAll
    cls.loadPlugin( entrypoint )
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\arrays\formathandler.py", line 44, in loadPlugin
    plugin_class = entrypoint.load()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\plugins.py", line 14, in load
    return importByName( self.import_path )
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\plugins.py", line 28, in importByName
    module = __import__( ".".join(moduleName), {}, {}, moduleName)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.1-py2.6-win32.egg\OpenGL\arrays\numpymodule.py", line 25, in 
    from OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler import NumpyHandler
  File "numpy.pxd", line 30, in OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler (src\numpy_formathandler.c:3543)
ValueError: numpy.dtype does not appear to be the correct type object
```

Sorry for the length of the post, I just wanted to fully document the problem. The Py install is running on Win XP SP3, IDLE header:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked in my case,

1. went to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyOpenGL-accelerate and downloaded the zip **source** package.
2. using 7zip I extracted the package to a folder named **PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.0.1**
3. then using a command prompt, navigated to the folder I just created
4. I typed **C:\python26\python setup.py install** to execute the package install

   Once this completed, I ran a basic OpenGL script in IDLE, Dr.Python, and PythonWin. All three IDEs were able to create the correct OpenGL window (a 400x400 window, black background, and a white wire-frame teapot.) without any errors. With this solution I was able to keep Numpy 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

The numpy Cython extension for OpenGL was probably built with numpy 1.3.x. So either you recompile OpenGL (especially the Cython extension) with your new numpy version or you downgrade numpy to 1.3.x. (if this does not help try to downgrade to 1.4.x and 1.5.x as well - as I do not exactly know what changed in what version).

Comment: When you say re-compile. do you mean the python script files from py to pyc or do I need h/cpp files to compile and create a re-vised version of lib/dll files? I have the pyopengl msi file (from the install but also have the zip file).  By the way, I also had this problem with numpy 1.5 superpack for py 2.6 .

Comment: you could recompile the C/CPP files manually but I do not know much about Windows. Alternatively you just download old numpy installers from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/

Comment: I tried down-grading numpy 1.6 first to 1.5, then to 1.3, but still the same thing, if I type the OpenGL code interactively, it works, when I load it as a file I get the same problem.  My last resort will be to completely uninstall Py 2.6 and then incrementally add each module and test.  Recompiling the C++ opengl code will crash all the other C/C++ apps that use it, so I'm trying to avoid that.